# Knowing whether window.close() will show a security warning

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

In IE7, a child window opened with `window.open` can close itself using `window.close()`, but a window opened with `<a href=... target=_blank>` will show a security warning if the child window tries to close itself.

In my application, I don't know how my child window is opened, and I need to know (in the child window JavaScript code) whether I can use the `window.close()` or not. Is there a way? Another way to ask the question is - is there a way in IE to differentiate between a window opened via `window.open` vs a window opened via `target=_blank`.

I tried checking `window.opener` but in both cases, there is a value there, so this does not allow me to differentiate between the two cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source: [Close window without the prompt message in IE7](http://dotnetslackers.com/community/blogs/haissam/archive/2007/04/20/Javascript_3A00_-Close-window-without-the-prompt-message-in-IE7.aspx)

This is how to avoid the prompt according to the page above:

```
function WinClose(){
    window.open('','_self','');
    window.close();
}

<a href="#" onclick="WinClose();return false;">Close</a>
```

Is this a possible approach for your page?

Comment: This works. Thanks. I now have other problems that are IE8 specific, but I guess I'll post it in another question.

Answer (score 1):

Try comparing window.opener and window.self

Comment: Unfortunately, the window.opener in both cases is the correct one, i.e. the parent window that opened this child window.

Answer (score 0):

Just a blind shot, but you can try removing the onunload event in the window, in case it is there.

Comment: You're a genius! I would NEVER have thought that it was THAT simple to remove the warning. It works in IE8 at least. Will check it in IE7 too.

Comment: Nope. My bad. I probably HOPED it works, but it doesn't. BTW, the onunload event occurs AFTER the window.close warning happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the window.open events, you could give the new window a name (2nd parameter I think). You can then check for that name before applying window.close().

Comment: Yes, that works, except that I don't have control over the opening!